# Not finding opencv jar after installing with homebrew

Tags: java, macos, opencv, homebrew

After installing opencv 2.4.8.2 with homebrew, I can't seem to find the jar file in /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.8.2/share/OpenCV

I'm using Mavericks, any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour - annoying!

Comment: I installed it (2.4.9) using --with-java and the jar file is there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you forgot to specify --with-java parameter

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv --with-java
```

After compiling a jar file is in the path

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-249.jar
```

Comment: I get an "error:invalid option" when I choose --with-java. Any idea what to do ? I am using macOS Monterey and openjdk11

Answer (score 3):

I solved the question by installing ant (and the other dependencies of opencv) using homebrew and then using cmake to install opencv instead of homebrew. I downloaded opencv from the website then used the following commands:

```
cd opencv-2.4.8/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make -j8
```

The jar will pop out in the following directory:

```
opencv-2.4.8/build/bin/opencv-248.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and tried with the `--with-java` option and it didn't work.

I had to edit the formula (`brew edit opencv3`) and insert this options myself:

```
option "with-contrib", "With contrib"
option "with-java", "With java"
```

Just above the dependency declarations.

You will also have to ensure that `-DBUILD_opencv_java=ON` is in your `args`. Note that the value is set to `ON` not `OFF`

After you've done this. Uninstall opencv then install it again.

Comment: When I try this I get an error saying "invalid-option: --with-java". Did you do anything else ? I am on Mac OS Monterey and using OpenJDK 11

Answer (score 0):

The error could just be because `-DBUILD_opencv_java` is not enabled. Enable it using `brew edit opencv3`